# Function to solve fractions does not work with negative numbers or zeros

Tags: python, function, fractions

```
def fraction(a=None, b=None):
    if a is None:
         a = int(input("Enter the value of a "))
    if b is None:
         b = int(input("Enter the value of b "))
    for i in range(1, min(a, b) + 1):
        if a % i == 0 and b % i == 0:
            gcf = i
    print(a//gcf, "/", b//gcf)

fraction()
```

I would like for this to add a negative number to the front of the fraction when 1 input is negative and have no change when both are negative. For 0's, if the denominator is 0 produce an output of "invalid" and if the numerator is 0 have an output of 0.

However, my `i in range` is stopping this from happening. How could I try solving this issue?

Answer (score 1):

First make sure that `b` is not negative. If it is, flip both signs. And then use `abs(a)` in the `range`.

Your code should also initialise `gcf` to 1, as there is a possibility the loop will not make iterations (i.e. when `a` is 0). And as then `gcf` is already 1, you might as well start the loop at 2.

Also, don't do I/O in such a function; always separate I/O from algorithmic logic. Perform I/O tasks outside of the function.

Here is how it could work:

```
def fraction(a, b):
    if b < 0:
        a = -a
        b = -b
    gcf = 1
    for i in range(2, min(abs(a), b) + 1):
        if a % i == 0 and b % i == 0:
            gcf = i
    return a//gcf, b//gcf


a = int(input("Enter the value of a "))
b = int(input("Enter the value of b "))
a, b = fraction(a, b)
print(a, "/", b)
```

Note that there are [more efficient algorithms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greatest_common_divisor#Calculation) for getting the greatest common divisor.